# how to use swTableView in Xamarin IOS.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am totally new to C# and starting with xamarin IOS code. i am basically from native app background.
i wanted simple app showing how to use swTableView controller in xamarin to show table as mention below.

Like :

```
ColumnNam   ColumnNam   ColumnNam   ColumnNam
data1       data2       data3        data4
data5       data6       data7        data8
```

i tried search for the example but i did not find one...if any one already has information please let me know..

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no system control can perform effect like you need, you must customize one, I write a sample for you to reference:

In ViewController.cs:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        this.Title = "testTalbeView";
        this.View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        UITableView tableView = new UITableView (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        tableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        tableView.Source = new MyTableSource ();
        this.Add (tableView);
    }
```

MyTableSource.cs:

```
public class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private string cellID = "MyCell";
    private int columns = 2;
    private List<string> dataList;

    public MyTableSource ()
    {
        dataList = new List<string> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            dataList.Add ("data " + i.ToString ());
        }
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of UITableViewSource

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return dataList.Count / columns + 1;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        MyCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellID) as MyCell;
        if (null == cell) {
            cell = new MyCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellID);
            cell.TextLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        }

        int row = (int)indexPath.Row;
        if (0 == row) {
            cell.SetData ("Column0", "Column1");
        }
        else{
            cell.SetData (dataList [(row-1) * columns], dataList [(row-1) * columns + 1]);
        }
        return cell;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

MyCell.cs:

```
public class MyCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private UILabel lbC0;
    private UILabel lbC1;

    public MyCell (UITableViewCellStyle style,string cellID):base(style,cellID)
    {
        lbC0 = new UILabel ();
        lbC0.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        this.AddSubview (lbC0);

        lbC1 = new UILabel ();
        lbC1.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        this.AddSubview (lbC1);
    }

    public void SetData(string str0,string str1)
    {
        lbC0.Text = str0;
        lbC1.Text = str1;
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        nfloat lbWidth = this.Bounds.Width / 2;
        nfloat lbHeight = this.Bounds.Height;
        lbC0.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, lbWidth, lbHeight);
        lbC1.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (lbWidth, 0, lbWidth, lbHeight);
    }
}
```

Then you can get the tableView like the picture:

[image: effect image]

Hope it can help you.